# `ctags` has no `options` argument, cannot build workspace symbols

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

`Cmd+T` should change focus to the top bar, with a hash in it (similar to `Cmd+Shift+O`).
Instead, nothing happens, and the below errors are thrown in output and developer console, respectively.

I believe this is a bug caused by the fact that the `ctags` being used is Emacs's `ctags` (version 25.3), which has no options keyword. Should I install a version of `ctags` using brew? If so, how do I get VS Code to recognize the new `ctags` without symlinking over the Emacs ctags in `/usr/local/bin/`?

### Environment data

VS Code Version: 1.41.0
Commit: 9579eda04fdb3a9bba2750f15193e5fafe16b959
Date: 2019-12-11T17:58:38.338Z
Electron: 6.1.5
Chrome: 76.0.3809.146
Node.js: 12.4.0
V8: 7.6.303.31-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 18.7.0

Extension Name: Python
Id: ms-python.python
Version: 2019.11.50794
Publisher: Microsoft

- Python version: python 3.6.9 (anaconda)
- Type of virtual environment used: `conda`
- `"python.jediEnabled"` is `true`.

### Logs

```
----------Generating Tags----------
ctags --options=~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/resources/ctagOptions --languages=Python --exclude=**/site-packages/** -o /Users/{...}/.vscode/tags .
> ctags --options=~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/resources/ctagOptions --languages=Python --exclude=**/site-packages/** -o ~/{...}/.vscode/tags .
cwd: ~/{...}
ctags: unrecognized option '--options=~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/resources/ctagOptions'
    Try 'ctags --help' for a complete list of options.
```

Output from `Console` under the `Developer Tools` panel:

```
console.ts:137 [Extension Host] Info Python Extension: 2019-12-12 12:48:32: Cached data exists getEnvironmentVariables, ~/{...}
console.ts:137 [Extension Host] Info Python Extension: 2019-12-12 12:48:33: Cached data exists getEnvironmentVariables, <No Resource>
console.ts:137 [Extension Host] Info Python Extension: 2019-12-12 12:48:33: > ctags --options=~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/resources/ctagOptions --languages=Python --exclude=**/site-packages/** -o ~/{...}/.vscode/tags .
console.ts:137 [Extension Host] Info Python Extension: 2019-12-12 12:48:33: cwd: ~/{...}
console.ts:137 [Extension Host] Info Python Extension: 2019-12-12 12:48:33: Cached data exists getEnvironmentVariables, extension-output-#2
```

Answer (score 0):

The extension is designed to work with exuberant ctags which is probably where you're having issues. As for specifying a path to ctags, use the [`"python.workspaceSymbols.ctagsPath"` setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference#_workspace-symbol-tags-settings).